# Decoding JSON Mapbox

Tags: php, json, maps, decode

Hi I want to get the geometry value from JSON to array PHP

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "query": [
    "maryland"
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "id": "address.2353009224859362",
      "type": "Feature",
      "place_type": [
        "address"
      ],
      "relevance": 1,
      "properties": {
        "accuracy": "street"
      },
      "text": "Maryland Drive",
      "place_name": "Maryland Drive, Maryland New South Wales 2287, Australia",
      "center": [
        151.6501385,
        -32.8792472
      ],
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          151.6501385,
          -32.8792472
        ]
      },
```

what i can do right now just

```
$json1 = json_decode($json,true);
$json1['features']
```

the problem is I have tried to access

```
$json1['features][0]
```

but it won't give me any results

Comment: Do you have any warnings errors in your php ?

Comment: Is your last example of `$json1['features][0]` a typo I presume? Because it should have a closing quotation `$json1['features'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Is your Json Valid ?
As I took it from what you typed it is incomplete ...

I made changes to make it valid and now it's working well :

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "query": [
    "maryland"
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "id": "address.2353009224859362",
      "type": "Feature",
      "place_type": [
        "address"
      ],
      "relevance": 1,
      "properties": {
        "accuracy": "street"
      },
      "text": "Maryland Drive",
      "place_name": "Maryland Drive, Maryland New South Wales 2287, Australia",
      "center": [
        151.6501385,
        -32.8792472
      ],
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          151.6501385,
          -32.8792472
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}';
$data = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']);
```

Outputs :

> Array (
>       [0] => 151.6501385
>       [1] => -32.8792472 )

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$coordinates = $data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'];
//print_r($coordinates);
echo implode(' ', $coordinates);
```

Comment: how to convert it into string ? the output that you get?

Comment: This basic php features, you have to explicit your needs more, anyway you can use implode 
$coordinates = $data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'];
echo implode(' ', $coordinates);
This will show : 151.6501385 -32.8792472

Comment: you can play with code here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c6e197cbae544e9be54c9e5478b62af5e6393d3